# is it possible to read a previous node by XMLReader?

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I know XMLReader can only move forward. In my program I may need to go back to read a previous node from XML file again and I don't like to use DOM, do we have any tricky way to do it?

Comment: Just remember the information you need from current node, right before advancing to next node. This way, you always have access to data from two nodes - the one the reader is positioned at now, and the previous one.

Comment: This might be of interest to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15610303/is-there-a-possibility-for-cloning-an-xmltextreader-or-multi-pass-reading

Comment: BTw. which XMLReader API are you referring to exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem.I found the line which i am looking for from System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(string filePath) and make another for loop backward.

```
string[] text = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);   
 for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
        {
            string currentLine= text[i];
            if (item.Contains("<s") && item.Contains("no=\"" + numberThatIamLookFor))
            {
                for (int j = i; j >0; j--)
                {
                    string previousLine= text[j];

                    if (previousLine.Contains("<p"))
                    {
                        ...
                    }
                    else if (previousLine.Contains("<p2"))
                    {
                        ...
                    }
                    else if(önceki.Contains("<p3"))
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }
```